# How to create a function using the following?

Tags: calculus, functions

I was absent when this was taught and I am cannot find how to solve this problem.
The question says: create a function connecting these points A(0,-4),B(4,0),C(7,3),D(10,3),E(12,0),F(14, -3), which represents velocity over 14 mins. At t=0, it was 37 miles east of a location. What is its velocity at t=3? What is the location at t=14? When was it farthest to the left? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wow. First, let me repeat my suggestion that when you miss a class, you get the notes from someone. But for this problem, which makes no sense whatsoever the way you have presented it, you had better give it to us word-for-word the way it was given to you. Meanwhile, voting to close as not a real question.

Comment: "its location"...whose location? Perhaps I'm missing something , but the question doesn't make much sense to me as it is.

Comment: Not a good idea to miss sciences classes ,uh? Unless, of course, that day was oneself's own funeral and/or there was an atomic attack on the university.

Comment: I'm voting to close, too.

Comment: The question says: create a function connecting these points A(0,-4),B(4,0),C(7,3),D(10,3),E(12,0),F(14, -3), which represents velocity over 14 mins. At t=0, it was 37 miles east of a location. What is its velocity at t=3? What is the location at t=14? When was it farthest to the left?

Comment: Oh ,that's pretty different! Well, there are infinite such functions, but I guess the intention here is to connect those points by means of straight line segments...? and I'm guessing the y-axis represents distance of object from something...

Comment: I guess, everything I said above is the whole problem so I am confused on how I would solve this.

Comment: Farthest...from what?!

Comment: I'm guessing the location of a t value?

Comment: I think there's enough information now for someone to make a stab at answering the question. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=t$, $y=v$
Your function is 
$$f(x)=\{x-4  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(0\le x<7)
\\\{3  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(7\le x<10)
\\\{18-3x/2  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(10\le x<14)$$

At $t=3$, $v=-1$.

To find displacements, integrate the ares for distinct regions, namely, over six distinct regions, when, v is negative, positive increasing, constant, positive decerasing, negative.
Negative means, travel in opposite direction. From, now, you know how to calculate velocity, acceleration (take derivative of functions, if needed) and displacement. from, this you can calculate what you need. Note, I think it's wiser to consider only East and West.

Also, you will have to decide which direction is positive? I mean which direction the car was heading initially. May be east as well? Consider that.

Comment: I think that for $7\le x\lt10$ you meant $f(x)=3$.

Comment: Ah. yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have sufficient rep to comment, but points A,B,C lie on the straight line $f(x)=x-4$ and points D,E,F lie on the straight line $f(x)=18-3x/2$. These lines intersect at (8.8,4.8). It would be reasonable to suppose that some object was accelerating uniformly until $t=8.8$ and then decelerated uniformly at a different rate from then on.

One could use the first equation to calculate how far it had reached and how fast it was going when acceleration ceased, and then the second to calculate how far it had reached when velocity went to zero and turn-around happened.